# Adding struct pointer to a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a problem and I really dont know what to do.

I'am trying to insert "new students" to an student-array. The array contains pointers to the created structs. Can somebody find the error? It adds the student-structs to the array but especially the printing doesnt work.

It would be really helpful, if somebody could help me. :) PS: You can just copy the code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_HASH 10
typedef struct student
{
    unsigned int matnr;
    char *name;
    struct student *next_student;
} Student;

Student **hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH];

void insert_student (unsigned int matnr, char *name)
{
    Student *neuer_student = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    neuer_student->name = malloc(sizeof(*name)+1);
    neuer_student->matnr = matnr;
    strcpy(neuer_student->name, name);
    neuer_student->next_student = NULL;

    // Index im Hash-Array ermitteln
    int hash_index = matnr % 10;

    if(hash_tabelle[hash_index] == NULL)
    {
        neuer_student->next_student = hash_tabelle[hash_index];
        hash_tabelle[hash_index] = neuer_student;
    }
    else
    {      
        while(*hash_tabelle[hash_index] != NULL && (((*hash_tabelle[hash_index])->matnr - neuer_student->matnr) <= 0))
            hash_tabelle[hash_index] = &(*hash_tabelle[hash_index])->next_student;
        neuer_student->next_student = *hash_tabelle[hash_index];
        *hash_tabelle[hash_index] = neuer_student;
    }
}

void print_hash_tabelle()
{
    for(int i = 0; i != MAX_HASH - 1; i++){
        printf("%d)\t", i);

        hash_tabelle[i] = &(*hash_tabelle[i])->next_student;

        for(; hash_tabelle[i] != NULL; hash_tabelle[i] = &(*hash_tabelle[i])->next_student){
            printf("%s (%d)", (&(*hash_tabelle[i])->name), (&(*hash_tabelle[i])->matnr));
        }
        printf("\t");
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int matnr;
    char name[100];

    do
    {
        printf("Matrikelnummer:\t");
        scanf("%d", &matnr);
        fflush(stdin);
        getchar(); // um das \n aus dem Puffer zu kriegen und rauszuschmeißen
        printf("Name:\t\t");
        fgets(name, 30, stdin);
        insert_student(matnr, name);
    }
    while (matnr != 0);

    print_hash_tabelle();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "doesnt work" isn't a good description. *How* doesn't it work? What do you expect it to do and what is it doing instead? Have you done any basic debugging yourself such as using a debugger?

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(*name)+1);` - that would be allocating exactly **2** chars; *always*. `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does there. See [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).

Comment: `Student **hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH];` --> `Student *hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH];`

Comment: But if I change it to "Student *hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH];" this isnt an array of pointers right? My problem is, that it crashes with a SIGSEV.

Comment: @MaxLebold `Student table[N];` is an array of `Student`. `Student *table[N];` is an array of pointers to `Student`. What you have, `Student **hash_table[MAX_HASH];` is an array of pointer to pointer to `Student`. You have one-too-many levels of indirection.

Comment: @MaxLebold Of course, you need to rewrite the parts involved.

Comment: @WhozCraig is correct, your `malloc` call is not allocating enough space for the name, so the `strcpy` will (probably) overwrite heap memory (especially if the name is longer than 16 chars). This may be the cause of your SIGSEGV.

Comment: Your insert function is doing something strange with the next_student pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hash table is so simple... No need to use dereferencing for a fixed-size array of linked-list pointers.

**Step 1** - a hash table is a array of linked-list pointers.

> As @BLUEPIXY suggests:

```
Student *hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH];
```

**Step 2** - to allocate and free each linked-list, initialize each item to NULL.

> Otherwise, `if(hash_tabelle[hash_index] == NULL)` is Undefined
>   behavior in the function `insert_student()`.

```
void hash_init()
{
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_HASH;i++) {
        hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH]=NULL;
    }
}
```

**Step 3** - allocate enough char to store the `char *name` to `insert_student()`.

> As @ WhozCraig suggests, use `strlen()`.

```
void insert_student (unsigned int matnr, char *name)
{
    Student *neuer_student = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    neuer_student->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    neuer_student->matnr = matnr;
    strcpy(neuer_student->name, name);
    neuer_student->next_student = NULL;
```

**Step 4** - add the `neuer_student` in the `hash_tabelle[]` (function `insert_student()`)

> Warning: the index shall be included in the size of the array
>   [0..MAX_HASH[. (using `10` instead of `MAX_HASH` could become a bug).

```
int hash_index = matnr % MAX_HASH;
```

> When the `hash_tabelle[hash_index]` is NULL, simple store the
>   `neuer_student`. No need to modify `neuer_student->next_student`.

```
if(hash_tabelle[hash_index] == NULL)
{
    hash_tabelle[hash_index] = neuer_student;
}
```

> Else explore the linked-list of `hash_tabelle[hash_index]` to store
>   the `neuer_student` at the end.

```
else
{
    Student *tmp;

    tmp = hash_tabelle[hash_index];
    while (tmp->next_student!=NULL) {
        tmp = tmp->next_student;
    }
    tmp->next_student = neuer_student;
}
```

**Step 5** - to print the all items of the hash table (function `print_hash_tabelle()`)

> Reuse the same method to explore each linked-list pointer.
>
> Warning: explore all item from `0` to `MAX_HASH-1`

```
void print_hash_tabelle()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HASH; i++){ // ERR != MAX_HASH - 1; i++){
        printf("%d)\t", i);
        Student *tmp = hash_tabelle[i];
        while (tmp!=NULL) {
             printf("%s (%d)", tmp->name, tmp->matnr);
            tmp = tmp->next_student;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Step 6** - free the memory of each item of the `hash_tabelle[]`.

> 1. Free the allocated string `free(tmp->name);`.
> 2. Remove the current student `hash_tabelle[i] = tmp->next_student;`
> 3. Free the allocated student `free(tmp);`
> 4. Repeat until the end of the linked-list

That's all (no change in the `main()` except adding a call to `hash_free()` at the end).

```
void hash_free()
{
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_HASH;i++) {
        Student *tmp = hash_tabelle[i];
        while (tmp!=NULL) {
            free(tmp->name);
            hash_tabelle[i] = tmp->next_student;
            free(tmp);
            tmp = hash_tabelle[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_HASH 10

typedef struct student {
    unsigned int matnr;
    char *name;
    struct student *next_student;
} Student;

Student *hash_tabelle[MAX_HASH];

void insert_student (unsigned int matnr, char *name){
    Student *neuer_student = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    neuer_student->name = malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    strcpy(neuer_student->name, name);
    neuer_student->matnr = matnr;
    //neuer_student->next_student = NULL;

    int hash_index = matnr % MAX_HASH;
    Student head = { .next_student = hash_tabelle[hash_index] };
    Student *prev = &head, *curr = head.next_student;
    while(curr != NULL && curr->matnr <= neuer_student->matnr){
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next_student;
    }
    neuer_student->next_student = curr;
    prev->next_student = neuer_student;
    hash_tabelle[hash_index] = head.next_student;
}

void print_hash_tabelle(void){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HASH; i++){
        printf("%d)\t", i);
        for(Student *p = hash_tabelle[i]; p; p = p->next_student){
            printf("%s (%d)\t", p->name, p->matnr);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void free_hash_tabelle(void){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_HASH; i++){
        Student *p = hash_tabelle[i];
        while(p){
            Student *temp = p->next_student;
            free(p->name);
            free(p);
            p = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int matnr = -1;//for %d of scanf
    char name[100];

    while(1){
        printf("Matrikelnummer(-1 for end input): ");fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &matnr);
        if(matnr < 0)
            break;
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Name: ");fflush(stdout);
        fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
        insert_student(matnr, name);
    }

    print_hash_tabelle();
    free_hash_tabelle();

    return 0;
}
```